# Check the max length of the matching string given only the regex pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to get the max length of the matching string from a regex pattern?

For example i have this pattern: "\d{2,2}/\d{3,3}" which matches this string format: xx/xxx where x must be a number. I need to know the max length of the matching string (which is 6 in this case).
Parsing the regex pattern to calculate the max length is not the best solution because there will be much more complicated patterns than this one.

Comment: Why not check the length of what was matched? Or do you want to know before you actually do a match?

Comment: @atanasovska Do you mean the max length of actual substrings matched for a tested string, or the max length of ALL possible strings matched by this pattern from any string (even if none exist in the tested string)?

Comment: I actually need to know the max possible length before checking the match..

Comment: What should be the answer for `.+`?

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to automatically find the max length of possible matches from a (presumably) arbitrary regex? What would that be in aid of? Because @Toto is 100% on point, as soon as you have an unlimited repetition, any potential for finding the length of the match goes out the door. And that's not even the hardest part, there are many constructs that can still match bound length but are VERY hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One partial solution could be to use the [RandExp](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js) library.

In the following example, I use it to determine in an array of patterns the ones which have a fixed length and the ones which don't.

> Note: I'm using the `0.4.1` version which works in the browser without an additional module loader.

```js
(function () {

    var patterns = [
        "\d{2,2}/\d{3,3}", // fixed length
        "\d+/\d{3,}", // variable length
        "<([a-z]+)>(.*?)</\1>",  // variable length
        "<([a-z]{5})>\w{16}</\1>",  // fixed length
    ];

    function run() {
        patterns.forEach(function (pattern) {
            var matchingStrings = '';
            var i;
            var count = 10;

            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                var matchingString = new RandExp(new RegExp(pattern)).gen();
                matchingStrings += matchingString;
            }
            if (matchingString.length * count === matchingStrings.length) {
                // consider pattern as fixed
                console.log('pattern "' + pattern + '" has a fixed length of ' + matchingString.length + ' characters');
            }
            else {
                // consider pattern as variable
                console.log('pattern "' + pattern + '" has a variable length and thus an unknown number of characters');
            }
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run, false);

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases/download/v0.4.1/randexp.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure if i understand your requirement correctly. But `String.match(pattern)` returns an array of matched elements. So you can iterate on returned array and find the maximum length matched.